# phpMyAdmin GIS Visualization does not work with this query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, gis

I have a table which contains latitude and longitude information in `Decimal` format. I am successfully getting them as GIS POINT type with the following query but phpMyAdmin's GIS Visualization extension act as if this returns an empty data set.

```
SELECT name, PointFromText( Concat( 'POINT (', geo_lat, ' ', geo_long, ')' ) ) AS coordinates
FROM `users`
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

If I do `AsText(coordinates)` I can see that it is a valid point with correct lat/long values. Should I report this as a bug?

Comment: Please report this as a bug, attaching to the bug ticket a small export of your table's structure and data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought I might have done something wrong instead of it being a bug. I will report it as soon as possible.

Comment: The bug report https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4313/

Comment: In 2023 still unfixed with decimal digits in Lat or Lon